# Upgraded web application from Jquery 1.8.2 to 1.9.1, DatePicker acting weired

Tags: jquery, .net, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have upgraded the Jquery to  1.9.1 from 1.8.2 and I am using bootstrap CSS 3.3.0 even bootstrap is upgraded from version 2.0.0. after the upgrade I changed a lot of stuff, but i am unable to figure what is making the datepicker display text "Next" and "Prev" over the buttons. Below is the Jquery script for the date picker. How can I fix it?

```
$(function () {
 $("#Date_Start").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
        showOn: "both",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        buttonText: "Select Date",
        buttonImage: '../Images/calendar_icon.png',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#Date_Start").val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

[image]

Comment: Is that jQuery UI Datepicker? Did you also update jQuery UI resources?

Comment: Yes I updated the UI too

Comment: See if bootstrap is conflicting with jQuery UI -- remove bootstrap and see if the widget still renders incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the following reference. It is working fine after adding this reference!

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.base.css")
```